# Converting VB to C# gives me an Error for the word Information and Conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

I wanted to convert an old VB to C# and I ended up with this code

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input;
        int numbInt;
        double casesAverage;
        input = txtinput.Text;
        if (Information.IsNumeric(input))
        {
            numbInt = Conversions.ToInteger(input);
            if ((numbInt.ToString() ?? "") == (input ?? ""))
            {
                if (numbInt >= MINIMUM_LIMIT & numbInt <= MAXIMUM_LIMIT)
                {
                    cases += numbInt;
                    LstCases.Items.Add(input);
                    txtinput.Clear();
```

The error I keep getting is on the first if statement where it says Information.IsNumeric and then again I get the second error in the body of the first if statement where it says conversions.ToInteger

Comment: Use a different converter? Post the VB? (Don't just post some broken code generated from working code we can't see and ask how the broken code is broken). It looks a bit wacky, I'd use Convert.ToInt32 or int.TryParse and throw most that code away

Comment: Converting how? Manually? Using a tool? A deleted answer stated that `input` is uninitialized, which is true. That will cause your code to not compile.

Comment: If you really want a one to one conversion, add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll which should make those compile. That being said, I'd strongly urge not doing that and using the appropriate framework methods

Comment: @Kit I think the answer was deleted because `input` is declared and set a few lines later? I think the real issue is that the lines erroring are because they are specific to a Visual Basic namespace/DLL as stated.

Comment: Also, `&` is rarely the operator you want. You likely  want `&&`. And `int.TryParse` notwithstanding, if you want to guarantee a text box has numeric input, use a `NumericUpDown` control and it's `Value` property (cast to `int`) instead

Comment: Please add the original VB code.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 If it's old VB code, it may have been written before the VB equivalent of `&&` was added to the language.

Comment: `Information.IsNumeric` is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.  However, there is no `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversions.ToInteger`.  There is `Microsoft.VisualBaisc.Conversions.Int`, maybe that's what was intended.

Comment: `if (Int32.TryParse(input, out numbInt))` makes the conversion line unnecessary.